# Salesforce Health Cloud - Connect API Specifications

Tags: connect-api, health-cloud

Is there any way we can find API specifications (Open API) or JSON schema definitions for all Business Connect API resources and objects?

I am trying to build an integration between our salesforce health cloud and NHS PDS service but I can't seem to find any schema definitions. Having schema definition would help me to create DTO in middleware.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.health_cloud_object_reference.meta/health_cloud_object_reference/connect_resources_create_get_update_patients.htm

Comment: It seems like Health Cloud API can be mapped to FHIR Base 4 version and NHS API is on FHIR 4 + UK Extensions. This gives NHS API Payloads to being a bit different than FHIR Base 4 payloads. Will try to convert the payloads and see if this works. Without converting to Base 4 format, salesforce connect API wouldn't support it.